# Can I have an optional text field together with a drop-down?

Tags: dspace

I have a "dropdown" field with values coming from a `value-pairs` list. One of the values is "Other", and I'd like to have an extra text field that allows the user to specify what "other" is. Is there a way to do this in Dspace?

Options I considered:

1. make the field `qualdrop_value`. As I understand, the value in the dropdown becomes the qualifier to the field's `dc-element`, as it is for the field "Identifiers" in the standard (i.e., "traditional") form, and the text box becomes the value of the element. But my dropdown values are not valid qualifiers in the DC schema: they really just a set of predefined values plus a freeform entry when the value is not in this list.
2. use a controlled vocabulary, but don't close it. This seems a bit heavy-weight, as the set of valid values is flat and quite small (less than ten). It also has a drawback that it's not as easy for the user to see the predefined" values as it is when they're listed in a dropdown.
3. use something like `type-bind` to make a separate field "other detail" visible only when the dropdown has value "Other". Except that `type-bind` works only based on the value of `dc:type`, which my dropdown is not.

Comment: Hi, I hope this post can help you: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/25954776/1919069)

Comment: That's a start, except it modifies the Java source code. The submission form is defined in an XML file and can be collection-specific. Any thoughts how that would be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in DSpace without modifying the source code. The link already reported by euler in the comments provides a good guideline on how to customize DSpace to support this usecase:

[How to add textArea based on selection from a dropdown or radio button in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25954776/1919069)